# What are these two bitwise operators doing?

Tags: c++, audio, bit-manipulation, operators

Anyone mind explaining what the following expression is doing?

```
int someValue = (((buffer[position + 1] << 8) | buffer[position] & 0xff) << 16)
```

I get that  buffer[position + 1] << 8 is shifting 8 bits to the left, and that buffer[position] & 0xff is basically extracting those 8 bits, but what's the role of the "or" (|) and why is the whole thing being shifted 16 bits to left? Are they being erased? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose/context of this code, and why is the question tagged with both `java` and `c++`?

Comment: Please tag only the language you are talking about and add the definitions of all the variables involved.

Comment: You have two left parentheses and three right parentheses.

Comment: sorry guys, I am new at this! I never posted on stackoverflow before! haha :) Just fixed the post as per your recommendations! I was just really trying to understand what the operands were doing that's all! Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this is transforming two bytes into a 16-bit integer. The two bytes are at buffer[position] and buffer[position + 1].

First, the byte at position + 1 shifted left by 8 bits. Second, the first byte has its high-order bits cleared.

Then the two bytes are combined with the bitwise-or operator.

Then this number so far is shifted left 16 bits, presumably in order to have another 2 bytes put into the lower part of this integer.

Comment: Makes sense to me!! Thanks for the answer mate! :)